# Where else is IPSec used, besides with VPNs?

Tags: vpn, ipsec

IPSec is most commonly used to secure VPN traffic. Where else is this protocol suite used? What else can it be used for?

Comment: This is quite a broad question so it would be good if you could narrow down what you want to know exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually, it was primarily developed for IPv6 traffic. It doesn't have to be used for VPN's per say, but it is designed to be an end-to-end security scheme and can be used to secure communications for any application traffic across an IP network.

> Internet Protocol Security (IPsec) was originally developed for IPv6,
>   but found widespread deployment first in IPv4, for which it was
>   re-engineered. IPsec was a mandatory specification of the base IPv6
>   protocol suite,[3][21] but has since been made optional.[22]

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)